# Emulate natural instruments with midi keyboard

Tags: midi

I am looking for a program (preferably lightweight and free) that lets me use a casio keyboard with midi to play or emulate an array of instruments. I am not looking into audio production at all so programs like FL Studio or the like aren't required. So bottom line, I am looking just for an emulator of natural instruments, nothing more.

Comment: Most Casio keyboards on their own emulate an array of instruments - is it that you're looking for more realism?

Comment: exactly. more realism.

Comment: I think he wants to utilize the MIDI capability to reproduce sounds that are not on board the keyboard through some type of MIDI processing and MIDI capable output.

Comment: You're right @RockinCowboy